# How are git parent numbers assigned?

Tags: git

From the documentation for `git-rev-parse`:

> ^, e.g. HEAD^, v1.5.1^0
>
> ```
> A suffix ^ to a revision parameter means the first parent of that
> commit object. ^<n> means the <n>th parent (i.e. <rev>^ is equivalent
> to <rev>^1). As a special rule, <rev>^0 means the commit itself and is
> used when <rev> is the object name of a tag object that refers to a
> commit object.
> ```

I understand that git commits can have multiple parents, and that this syntax can be used to disambiguate which parent is referred to, but what determines which parent is the 'first parent' or 'second parent'? Is it just based on which commit was checked out when the commits were merged?

For example, would `git checkout master; git merge feature` result in `master` being parent 1, whereas `git checkout feature; git merge master` would result in `feature` being parent 1? Or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it just based on which commit was checked out when the commits were merged?

That's right.  You can look at the parents of a commit using `git show` or `git cat-file -p HEAD`.

Comment: Note also that "first parent" has a special flag (`--first-parent`) in `git rev-list`.  Git thus uses "first parent" as the "main thread" of a branch: you merge features in to the main line, making them non-first-parent, so by definition the first-parent must be the "mainline".

Answer (score 0):

Note there is a limit to the number of parents a commit can have.

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) illustrates that by fixing a bug related to said limit.

See [commit 59fa5f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59fa5f5a25d9ccc57558ac44cce83d37ac1cec58), [commit a678df1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a678df1bf928caeeef642ef07f73484a580fea57) (15 Sep 2019) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 773521d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/773521df2689cc3ada76495c5b4061753b510d32), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### `sha1-name`: check for overflow of `N` in "`foo^N`" and "`foo~N`"
>
> Reject values that don't fit into an `int`, as `get_parent()` and `get_nth_ancestor()` cannot handle them.
>   That's better than potentially returning a random object.
>
> If this restriction turns out to be too tight then we can switch to a wider data type, but we'd still have to check for overflow.

That is because of:

> ### rev-parse: demonstrate overflow of N for "foo^N" and "foo~N"
>
> If the number gets too high for an int, weird things may happen, as signed overflows are undefined.
>   Add a test to show this; `rev-parse` "successfully" interprets `100000000000000000000000000000000` to be the same as 0, at least on x64 with GCC 9.2.1 and Clang 8.0.1, which is obviously bogus.

So:

> what determines which parent is the 'first parent' or 'second parent'?

If you enter a too important number... you could end up with *any* parent.
Unless you are using Git 2.24 or more.